# How to parse a JSON file to create a list of specific class?

Tags: c#, json

I got this [JSON file](https://github.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/blob/master/countriesToCities.json) from this post on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794833/list-of-cities-by-country). I am pretty new to JSON and I am getting repeated errors while trying to parse the JSON file.
I tried this using [`JsonConvert`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm)

I have created a class to store the data as follows

```
public Class LocationInformation
{
    string Country {get; set;}
    List<string> Cities {get; set;}
}
```

I am getting lot of errors when I try to get the data from the location JSON file. When I tired with examples in other posts, I see that the JSON files are formatted in a different way where it specifies the data stored.

Comment: use Json.net (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: I used the same, but I don't know how to do this. Please see the JSON file it does not have any specifiers.

Comment: That json is perfectly valid. Show the code you are using to parse it

Comment: @Pikoh: I know the JSON is valid. However, I don't have enough knowledge to parse it the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` so deserialize it like this:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,List<string>>>(json);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/UZGC57402

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a look and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your model does not match the JSON.

Do this:

```
public List<LocationInformation> ParseMyJson()
{
  var file = ... // load file here;

  var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>(file);

  return data.Select(x => new LocationInformation { Country = x.Key, Cities = x.Value }).ToList(); // you DON'T have to return a list
}
```